# How do you perform bootstrapping and remove outliers in Weka?

Tags: data-mining, weka

I am just starting to play around with the Weka API and a couple of the example data sets, but just wanted to understand a couple bits and pieces. Does anyone know how to perform 0.632 bootstrapping in Weka?

Also how do would I go about detecting outliers (I understand there are many different methods of doing this...)?

Also how would I remove say 10% of outliers, once they have been identified?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 4):

You can perform supervised resampling, which is what bootstrap is, using the [Resample](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/filters/supervised/instance/Resample.html) filter.

Comment: Thank you for the advice michaeltwofish! I was thinking that... It's strange that Weka doesn't have bootstrapping as a built in function...